# Counting rows in multiple tables cause large delay

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables with mainly string data and unique id column:

```
categories ~45 rows
clientfuncs ~800 rows
serverfuncs ~600 rows
```

All tables have unique primary AI column 'id'.
I try to count rows in one query:

```
SELECT COUNT(categories.id), COUNT(serverfuncs.id), COUNT(clientfuncs.id) FROM categories, serverfuncs, clientfuncs
```

It takes 1.5 - 1.7 s.

And when I try

```
SELECT COUNT(categories.id), COUNT(serverfuncs.id) FROM categories, serverfuncs
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(categories.id), COUNT(clientfuncs.id) FROM categories, clientfuncs
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(clientfuncs.id), COUNT(serverfuncs.id) FROM clientfuncs, serverfuncs
```

, it takes 0.005 - 0.01 s. (as it should be)

Can someone explain, what is the reason for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing a cross join of 45*800*600 rows, you'll notice that when you check the result of the counts :-)

Try this instead:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM categories), 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM serverfuncs), 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM clientfuncs);
```

Answer (score 5):

The queries are doing [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) since no join condition is applied so:

```
1 query : 800*600*45 = 21,6 mil
2 query : 45*600     = 27 k
3 query : 45*800 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because your query is joining the tables (the commas in the last part of the query are shorthand for a join) rather than counting them individually. So your queries with only two tables will be quicker.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do you really want to use three tables in the FROM clause to compute counts that are specific to each table? This will cause the SELECT statement to produce a Cartesian product of the three tables which will result in a total number of rows of 45 x 800 x 600 from which counts are computed. Hence many duplicates of categories.id values will be counted and so are the other counts. In any case if you use first two tables in the FROM clause, the Cartesian product will contain only 45 X 800 rows which is much less than the rows the three tables produce. Hence the queries with two tables are much faster. Primary keys are of no use in this cases.

Better use three different statements to get count from each table.

If you still insist on getting counts at one shot, you may use the following syntax:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(categories.id) FROM categories), 
       (SELECT COUNT(serverfuncs.id) FROM serverfuncs), 
       (SELECT COUNT(clientfuncs.id) FROM clientfuncs);
```

if your RDBMS supports SELECT statements without FROM clause. These will give correct counts and would be very fast.